Is there a name for this type of puzzle?
Before, when I was searching for Jack Lance’s P.I HUNT puzzles, I found this petal crossword.
It is just like any other crossword, but the letters are replaced by a repeating fixed phrase. It is basically the same if you replaced every letter with ‘A’, for example. This isn’t even a cipher, if it were, it would be 99.9% irreversible. The same word may be written differently in different clues, and different words (with the same number of letters) can be written the same. For example, “crossword puzzle” and “extremely tiring” are practically indistinguishable.
You have to figure out what the clues actually say through the numbers, symbols and accents. For example, “A llwork andnoplay ma kesj 1 ack adullb, o.y. 2, 3, 5, 7” most likely translates to “A number divisible by only 1 and itself, e.g. 2, 3, 5, 7” and corresponds to the word PRIME, because of the numbers at the end and the “1”. Also, titles of movies and other media may have special characters, so they might be enough to identify the title.
Is there a name for those such puzzles, where all letters (or numbers, etc) of the text are replaced in a way that the transformation is irreversible without a lot of context? If so, can you please tell me what it is?

Not sure of the answer to your question, but a similar technique was employed to some extent by user HTM in this puzzle posted on PSE in 2021, which may be of interest to people interested in puzzles of this type.

This should be a question on the main site, not on meta. Please ask it on the main site. Meta Puzzling Stack Exchange is for dealing with the business of PSE: discussing what questions are on topic, how to use the website, reporting bugs in the design, etc. PSE itself accepts questions asking for puzzle terminology. You'll also get far more attention there.
